# How to rollback EF 7 migrations programmatically?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, database-migration, entity-framework-core

I would like to write a unit test which migrates to the latest schema then tears back down to nothing.

For the migration I can do :

```
db.Database.Migrate();
```

but how to I rollback?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Commands](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/tree/dev/src/EntityFramework.Commands) use something like this;

```
var migrator = db.GetInfrastructure().GetRequiredService<IMigrator>();
migrator.Migrate("Migration1");
```

Where *Migration1* is the name of the migration.  [This](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/92989dae4874b3bd2b06662a801f1e9b6127b8a2/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational/Migrations/IMigrator.cs) suggests you can stick "0" in there to roll them all back.

Comment: I can confirm this works as well as my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Was digging in the assemblies and found I can do this :

```
db.Database.GetService<IMigrator>().Migrate("0");
```